# Custom UITableViewCell items not displaying properly

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

my current issue goes like so:

I'm aiming to create a "home" view for my iPhone app. It needs to consist of a "featured" view (top part of the view on attached picture) and a feed-style table view below it:

[image]

The way I've designed it so far is to use a single table view with two different cell prototypes: one for the "featured" view (the big dark-blue cell with a scroll view and page control inside) and one for the "feed item" view (currently empty cell below it). Both have separate class files attached to them. I want the "featured" cell to be displayed only once on top of the view, followed by the "feed item" cells, all fed with content from an external backend.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      let cell: FeaturedItemCell = FeaturedStockCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "featuredItem")
      return cell
    default:
      let cell: HomeItemCell = HomeItemCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "homeItem")
      return cell
    }
}
```

Yet using the code above, all I'm getting in return is a bunch of empty white rows inside the table view.

So the questions are as follows:

1. What should I do to generate the cells as I've designed them? and
2. Is this approach the right one, or are there better ways to
   handle this issue?

Comment: Did you set the tableview's delegate and datasource methods?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already created the prototypes in the UITableView, the method for instantiating the cells becomes a little different.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var identifier: String
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        identifier = "featuredItem"
    default:
        identifier = "homeItem"

    }
    let cell: FeaturedItemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("featuredItem", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Comment: If you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier don't forget implement `registerClass:` or `registerNib` method for tableView in viewDidLoad method

Comment: @iSashok I don't think it's necessary while using storyboards, with both cell prototypes having their class assigned. Or is it?

Comment: if you create a custom cell in separate .xib file you need a registerNib

Comment: @ZeMoon that's a start, thanks much! But now I get the view populated with a small part of the blue cell at a default cell height, even though the height is set to a custom height of 400 in the size inspector. It also looks like the identifier variable is never used, like it never entered the switch statement at all. Do you have any idea on what may be the problem here?

Comment: Have you set the identifier in the properties inspector of each custom UITableViewCell? Also, you need to return the height of each cell in the tableview(tableview:, heightForRowAtIndexPath:) method